# Hubspot Contacts API not working by usertoken

Tags: json, api, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I am trying out the Contacts API (https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/get_batch_by_user_token_with_token_keys) and passing my API key and my own usertoken and it is returning a blank object.

```
{}
```

My API key seems correct (as it returns an error when I slightly change it) and the usertoken is the one I get from the __hsUserToken variable I get in the console of my web application (I am known in the Hubspot database and have filled out some forms etc already).
The demo (https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/utks/batch/?hapikey=demo&utk=6084e7de6a2b6f11f31d976090c4...) does return a record, so I am clueless. Does anyone have any I idea what I might be doing wrong or if there are any limitations to the API that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you're using? "This thing doesn't work" doesn't give us much to go on.  Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Phaelaxz as mentioned, when I just try to access the url, it returns an empty object while the demo url doesn't. I am using the exact same url as the demo with the apikey and the utk replaced by my own (which I can't share for obvious reasons)